# Command not found despite having just installed it?

Tags: bash, command-line, python, pip, command-not-found

As you can see in the screenshot below, I install a command (it's a wrapper for a program called qsiprep), and then try running it, but it says it's not installed...any ideas as to what is happening?

I believe it may have something to do with my Python bin not being on the path. That's all I could find on the net for searching this problem up. But I'm not exactly sure what it means...I can run python just fine, is the python bin separate from python?

Edit: the output from `find / -name 'qsiprep-container' is

```
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
find: ‘/usr/src/evdi-5.2.14’: Permission denied
find: ‘/snap/core18/1705/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘/snap/core18/1705/root’: Permission denied
find: ‘/snap/core18/1705/var/cache/ldconfig’: Permission denied
```

and many similar messages, all ending in "Permission denied." What should I be looking for here?

If I instead append the command with sudo, only one line is output:

`find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied`

[image]

Comment: Please cut and paste the formatted test from the shell rather than posting a picture. Your problem will be better indexed which will help both you and people with similar problem in the future.

Comment: @user1794469 ah good point, will do that!

Comment: Sorry, the package you are installing isn't an executable, what are you trying to run specifically? Or what is the tutorial you are following for installation?

Comment: @user1794469 I'm pretty sure that's the command I'm instructed to run. I think an equivalent command would be `qsiprep-docker`, would that be better? 
Also, how do you check if packages are executable or not? (PyPi doesn't seem to tell you off the bat I don't think?)

Comment: Are you using this? https://qsiprep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#docker-container make sure you have `docker` installed and the other dependencies that are listed on that page and try the commands listed.

Comment: Running `pip install —user ...` will make pip install in your home directory. Look in $HOME/.local/bin for executables and .local/lib for the libraries. (Technically look for it in : `python -c ‘import site; print(site.USER_SITE)’` )

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have it in your path. Try:

```
find / -name 'qsiprep-container'
```

to see where it was installed. It's also possible that that is the name of the package but not the executable/program. Make sure you are trying to run the correct target.

Comment: Thank you for the response! When I do `find / -name 'qsiprep-container'`, a bunch of random stuff is printed to the terminal. I've edited my post to give examples. Are you sure there are no typos in that command? If so, what exactly am I look for in the output?

Comment: whoops, i got a little ahead of myself. What are you trying to run? What is the executable?

Comment: I've confirmed that the target is indeed named `qsiprep-container` so I think I'd be looking for that

Comment: You can ignore the permission denied errors if you are running as a normal user.  It is entirely expected.